# (C++) Use other class' object as parameter in a class when two classes use each other's object

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing

My title sounds a little weird...
But my question is...

```
class A{
public:
    doSomething(B & b);
}

class B{
public:
    doSomething(A & a);
}
```

is this not supposed to work??

I get errors saying function does not take 1 parameter
because the identifier (classes) is undefined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type needs to be declared before it can be used. Since you have an interdependency between classes you need to use a forward declaration.

```
class B; // Forward declaration so that B can be used by reference and pointer
         // but NOT by value.

class A{ public: doSomething(B & b); }

class B{ public: doSomething(A & a); }
```

Note that this is generally considered a very bad design and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: How do I forwardly declare a class??

Comment: Use `class CLASSNAME;` where `CLASSNAME` is the name of the class you want to forward declare.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
public:
    doSomething(B & b);
};
```

is not ok , because the compiler is yet to know what B is , which is defined latter.

Compiler Always works from a top-down approach , so it must have seen a class (either declared or defined) , before it is being used elsewhere , so your code should be

```
class A; // Not reqd in your case , but develop a good programming practice of using forward declaration in such situations
class B; // Now class A knows there is asnothed class called B , even though it is defined much later , this is known as forward declaration

class A{
public:
    doSomething(B & b);
}

class B{
public:
    doSomething(A & a);
}
```